# Understanding a weird SQL clause

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, mariadb, where-clause, clause

While learning some SQL, I stumbled upon this seemingly incorrect clause:

```
SELECT item 
FROM inventory 
WHERE 20 >= price < 500;
```

The query does not result what was intended and should look like this:

```
SELECT item 
FROM inventory 
WHERE price >= 20 AND price < 500;
```

I know that there is a better way to solve this. What really interests me here is why is the first query showed not failing at all? It returns results, sure not the ones we want but I expected it to fail completely.

Can someone help me to understand what the first query does at all? I couldn't find any useful information.

Comment: Which SQL "dialect" / RDBMS is this for/on ?

Comment: Oh sorry. It is Mysql tested on a mariadb

Comment: What was the result of the first query? I've never seen that syntax before and it fails in a fiddle.

Comment: I'm guessing it is actually >= not =>.  Please, when asking questions try to copy/paste what you are actually trying?

Comment: _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '> price < 500' at line 3_ https://dbfiddle.uk/Zoag1c-0

Comment: `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` will show something like `((20 => price) < 500)`, which is how your original expression will be evaluated.  (`SHOW WARNINGS;`)

Comment: This happens because MySQL does not have a bona fide boolean type. It accepts integer values in their place.

Comment: as already pointed out by others the operator was >=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
20 >= price < 500
```

is equivalent to

```
(20 >= price) < 500
```

because of operator precedence. In MySQL, boolean values are the integers 1 (for TRUE) and 0 (for FALSE). So if `20 >= price` is true, it's equivalent to

```
1 < 500
```

If that part if false, it's equivalent to

```
0 < 500
```

Either way, the combined condition will be true, so the `WHERE` condition will result in all rows being returned.

There are some languages where you can write expressions like this; Python allows "chained comparisons", automatically treating them as combined with `and`. So one can write

```
if 20 <= price < 500:
```

to test if the price is between 20 and 500. SQL doesn't have this, but it does have a built-in `BETWEEN` operator:

```
WHERE price BETWEEN 20 AND 499
```

(since `BETWEEN` is inclusive, you have to subtract to get the equivalent of `<` instead of `<=`).

The original code is also nonsensical for another reason: If a number is less than 500, it will also be less than or equal to 20. So `20 >= price` is redundant. Are you sure it wasn't `20 <= price` (I notice that you swapped the order of arguments to `>=` when you wrote the "corrected" version)?

Comment: Thank you so much! That explains it well :-)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL comparison operators return 0 or 1 (or null), and that return itself can be used in a comparison.

```
20 >= price < 500
```

is doing the comparison 20 >= price, then seeing if the 0 or 1 or null is < 500 (which it will be, unless price is null).  So the overall expression will be either 1 (true) or null.

Comment: Thank you too. Thats exactly what i was missing